# how to design a fallback for a spring integration service activator with circuit breaker?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

when a circuit breaker advice is triggered, this takes care not to overload the failing integration service.

How do i fallback to a different service activator when the circuit is open? and when the circuit becomes closed need to fallback to primary activator

Is there a way to implement this with the framework? or some custom code has to be written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an inline gateway to catch the exceptions and send them to an error channel; you can then use a router on the error flow to decide how to proceed further. Hopefully the following is reasonably easy to follow...

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="inbound" ref="gw" />

<int:gateway id="gw" default-request-channel="toPrimary"
    error-channel="failures" 
    default-reply-timeout="0" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="toPrimary" expression=" 1 / 0 ">
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice">
            <property name="threshold" value="2" />
            <property name="halfOpenAfter" value="10000" />
        </bean>
    </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int:service-activator>

<!-- Error flow -->

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="failures" />

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="failing" channel="failures" />

<int:recipient-list-router input-channel="failures" default-output-channel="nullChannel" >
    <int:recipient channel="circuitFailures" selector-expression="payload.message.contains('Expression evaluation failed:  1 / 0') || payload.cause.message.contains('Circuit Breaker is Open')" />
</int:recipient-list-router>

<int:chain input-channel="circuitFailures" output-channel="loggingChannel">
    <int:transformer expression="payload.failedMessage" />
    <int:service-activator expression="payload + ' failed'" />
</int:chain>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggingChannel" log-full-message="false" logger-name="tapInbound"
    level="INFO" />
```